# How to sum the parent ID values and show in place of null

Tags: mysql

Hi I have query which returns me data

```
SELECT
     s.StandardID,
     s.StandardName as Standard,
     TableA.Score,
     Dropdown1.Name as dq,
     Standard.ParentStandardID,         
     Standard.Weight     
FROM TableA
      JOIN Standard ON Standard.StandardID = TableA.StandardID
```

Results

```
+------------+----------+-------+------------------+---------+
| StandardID | Standard | Score | parentstandardid |  weight |
+------------+----------+-------+------------------+---------+
|    1       |     A    |       |      3           |    o    |
+------------+----------+-------+------------------+---------+
|   107      |     B    |       |     NULL         |    1    |
+------------+----------+-------+------------------+---------+
|   111      |     C    |       |      1           |   107   |
+------------+----------+-------+------------------+---------+
|   112      |     D    |       |      2           |   107   |
+------------+----------+-------+------------------+---------+
```

Now where score is null, i want to show sum of scores of corersponding          parents ids. If standardID is 107 and score null than score should be sum of parents ids 107. No group by to be used ans if not null than score remains same.

ANy help would be appreciated
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Select

S.StandardID,
  (CASE WHEN A.Score IS NULL THEN C.Score ELSE A.Score END ) AS New_Score

FROM Table A

INNER JOIN Standard S ON S.StandardID = TableA.StandardID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
 SELECT S1.ParentStandardID, SUM(B.ScoreValue )  Score
 FROM Table B, Standard S1 WHERE S1.StandardID = B.StandardID
 GROUP BY ParentStandardID
) C
ON S.StandardID = C.ParentStandardID